# GuzzleHTTP: POST Request magically turns to GET request giving me "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: php, http, guzzle

I have a PHP file example.php and inside this file l have entered the code below

```
$client->request('POST', $postURL, ['headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization'=>'Token t6wdjjd7787sjjhd87954frr']], ['json' => $post_data] );
```

when l visit my web browser to test the request localhost:8000/example.php

I get the error 405 GET not allowed, meanwhile the request am making is a POST request

What am l doing wrongly here?

I am using Apache Server, GuzzleHTTP 6, PHP 5.6

Comment: what server and framework are you running? Some basic info about your environment would help

Comment: I am using Apache Server, GuzzleHTTP 6, PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $client->request('POST', $postURL, ['headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization'=>'Token t6wdjjd7787sjjhd87954frr'],'body'=>$post_data]] );
```

You have 4 parameters, method should be 3 parameters:

1. Method
2. URI
3. Options array.

Comment: This is not an issue because the requests goes through without any problem with the syntax.

Comment: What is the 4th parameter ?

Comment: The 4th Parameter is the POST Data am sending to the API request and it is in JSON

Comment: I update my answer, try to put the data in options => body instead of another parameter. I feel that it will fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe the remote server doesn't allow POST method, the type of the remote server ? 3rd party or you can access into ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139020/discussion-between-4each-and-ernest-appiah).